# How to raise an exeption that tells me in what loop I was in?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following input to an `assign_points(lists)` function:

```
[['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
['0', '0', '10', '10', '0', '0', '10', '10', '0', '0', '0', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '0', '0', '0'],
['0', '0', '10', '10', '0', '0', '10', '10', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '10', '10', '0', '0'],
['0', '0', '10', '10', '0', '0', '10', '10', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '10', '10', '0', '0'],
['0', '0', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '0', '0', '0', '0', '10', '10', '10', '10', '0', '0', '0'],
['0', '0', '0', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '0', '0', '0', '10', '10', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '10', '10', '0', '0', '0', '10', '10', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '10', '10', '0', '0', '0', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '0', '0'],
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']]
```

And in my code I have something like:

```
def A(point):
    try:
        #something
        B(val_1, val_2, val_3)
    except ValueError:
        #It should quit here but I want to say what line and item (Y, X loop) it was in


def B(val_1, val_2, val_3):
    try:
        ...
    except ValueError:
        #It should quit here but I want to say what line and item (Y, X loop) it was in

def assign_points(lists)
    for y, list in enumerate(lists):
        for x, point in enumerate(list):
            A(point)
```

I have a function `B()` inside of a function `A()` inside two `for` loops.
If there's anything wrong inside the function B I want to raise an exception that gives me what loop it was on.

I know I can pass x and y but I feel like it bloats the code and makes it less reusable. I was wondering if there was an alternative to that.
I want the exception to say " item on  line is improperly formatted"

Is this possible to do?

Comment: @Luke not quite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither A nor B know (nor should know) about the outer iteration. But `assign_points` knows exactly where it is. Move the exception handling there.

```
def A(point):
    B(val_1, val_2, val_3) # exception raised in here

def B(val_1, val_2, val_3):
        ... an exception raised here

def assign_points(lists)
    for y, list in enumerate(lists):
        for x, point in enumerate(list):
            try:
                A(point)
            except ValueError as e:
                print(x, y, e)
```

If you need context information from the lower level functions, they could catch ValueError and reraise with details. Perhaps by adding attributes to the existing exception or creating a new one with the specifics.

For example

```
class BError(Exception):
    
    def __init__(self, val_1, val_2, val_3):
        self.val_1 = val_1
        self.val_2 = val_2
        self.val_3 = val_3
        self.message = f"{val_1}, {val_2}, {val_3} are super bad"
        super().__init__(self.message)

def A(point):
    B(val_1, val_2, val_3) # exception raised in here

def B(val_1, val_2, val_3):
    try:
        .... calculation raises ValueError
    except ValueError as e:
        raise BError(val_1, val_2, val_3)

def assign_points(lists):
    x = y = None
    try:
        for y, list in enumerate(lists):
            for x, point in enumerate(list):
                A(point)
    except BError as e:
        print(x, y, e)
```

There are lots of options here. For instance, perhaps BError should keep the original error message. But you get the idea.

Comment: How can I use a more personalised error?

Comment: @MiguelP You can raise any exception that you want. If `B` has information to add to the exception, you can put something like `try: ... except ValueError as ex: raise SpecialException("personalized", "info") from ex` in `B`

Comment: @MiguelP - Added an example using a custom error.